# Enumeration and mapping with Scala 2.10

Tags: scala, dictionary, mapping, enumeration, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to port my application to Scala 2.10.0-M2. I'm seeing some nice improvements with better warnings from compiler. But I also got bunch of errors, all related to me mapping from `Enumeration.values`.

I'll give you a simple example. I'd like to have an enumeration and then pre-create bunch of objects and build a map that uses enumeration values as keys and then some matching objects as values. For example:

```
object Phrase extends Enumeration {
  type Phrase = Value
  val PHRASE1 = Value("My phrase 1")
  val PHRASE2 = Value("My phrase 2")
}

class Entity(text:String)

object Test {
    val myMapWithPhrases = Phrase.values.map(p => (p -> new Entity(p.toString))).toMap  
}
```

Now this used to work just fine on Scala 2.8 and 2.9. But 2.10.0-M2 gives me following warning:

```
[ERROR] common/Test.scala:21: error: diverging implicit expansion for type scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[common.Phrase.ValueSet,(common.Phrase.Value, common.Entity),That]
[INFO] starting with method newCanBuildFrom in object SortedSet
[INFO]   val myMapWithPhrases = Phrase.values.map(p => (p -> new Entity(p.toString))).toMap
                                                 ^
```

What's causing this and how do you fix it?

Comment: I'm not getting this with the above snippet. Is this part of a larger file, and are there other definitions, imports in there?

Comment: No, this is just an artificial example, shortest way of causing the compilation error. Normally there would be a bigger application instead of the `object Test` using the map.

Comment: I think this is a bug... well, not exactly a bug, but certainly an unintended consequence. I'd open a ticket about it.

Comment: Issue filed: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5534

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's basically a type mismatch error. You can work around it by first converting is to a list:

```
scala> Phrase.values.toList.map(p => (p, new Entity(p.toString))).toMap
res15: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Phrase.Value,Entity] = Map(My phrase 1 -> Entity@d0e999, My phrase 2 -> Entity@1987acd)
```

For more information, see the answers to [What's a “diverging implicit expansion” scalac message mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950014/whats-a-diverging-implicit-expansion-scalac-message-mean) and [What is a diverging implicit expansion error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883906/what-is-a-diverging-implicit-expansion-error)

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Would be nice if someone could give the reason for the need of it too.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from your error, the ValueSet that holds the enums became a SortedSet at some point.  It wants to produce a SortedSet on map, but can't sort on your Entity.

Something like this works with case class Entity:

```
implicit object orderingOfEntity extends Ordering[Entity] {
  def compare(e1: Entity, e2: Entity) = e1.text compare e2.text
}
```

Comment: `but can't sort on your Entity.` Why not?

Comment: @KevinMeredith the CanBuildFrom on map requires an Ordering: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0-RC2/scala/collection/SortedSet$.html#newCanBuildFrom[A]%28implicitord:Ordering[A]%29:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[scala.collection.SortedSet.Coll,A,scala.collection.SortedSet[A]]