# Scala - diverging implicit expansion when using toMap

Tags: scala, dictionary, implicit-conversion

I have the following definition of an enum:

```
object GraphType extends Enumeration {
  type Type = Value
  val MESSAGE, REQUEST, ERRORS = Value
}
```

Now I am trying to map each of the type to the corresponding, new `TimeSeries` as follows:

```
val dataSets = ( GraphType.values map (graphType => graphType -> new TimeSeries(graphType)) ).toMap
```

the type system lists datasets as `Map[GraphType.Value, TimeSeries]` which is precisely what I want. However, compilation fails with error message:

```
error: diverging implicit expansion for type scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[ird.replay.gui.GraphType.ValueSet,(ird.replay.gui.GraphType.Value, org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries),That]
starting with method newCanBuildFrom in object SortedSet
val dataSets = GraphType.values map (graphType => graphType -> new TimeSeries(graphType)) toMap
```

COuld anyone provide some explanation for this, rather cryptic, error message? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enumeration and mapping with Scala 2.10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487425/enumeration-and-mapping-with-scala-2-10)

Answer (score 4):

Try converting the Set of values for the enum to a `List` first like so:

```
val dataSets = (GraphType.values.toList.map(gt => (gt, new TimeSeries(gt)))).toMap
```

Something about that being a Set did not agree with how you were attempting to convert it to a `Map`, but it seems to work just fine with a `List`

Comment: It's because enum.values is now a **Sorted**Set. The issue doesn't come with the "toMap" conversion but happens before with the map function on the SortedSet: its output (here the TimeSeries, I guess) can't be sorted. Hence, the error.