# Rich enumeration with iteration in Scala

Tags: scala, enumeration

I am trying to implement a Rich enumeration in Scala, where my enumeration would also have to implement for example a trait.

This work fine, however when I tried to iterate the enumerations, the Enumeration.values returns a ValueSet, which is a collection of Enumeration.Value

Is there a simple way to implement this feature, without going to macros and sealed traits are suggested from Travis Brown [Iteration over a sealed trait in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671734/iteration-over-a-sealed-trait-in-scala) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to convert first:

[Enumeration and mapping with Scala 2.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487425/enumeration-and-mapping-with-scala-2-10)

I guess both answers there are relevant, but I'd totally forgotten mine.

This thread

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-internals/8RWkccSRBxQ/snNuzjJakhkJ

might mark the start of the long road to the enum replacement.  It contains a few divergent (pun alert) opinions on usage.

Early stop on the road:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4346618/1296806

Comment: I think the last link says it correctly: "Honestly, I wouldn't use Enumeration. This is a class originating from Scala 1.0 (2004) "

Answer (score 3):

Enumeration in scala can be done relatively easy with an Enumeration class. Below is an example of it.

```
trait Num {
  def echo
}

object Status extends Enumeration {

  case class StatusVal(code: Int, name: String) extends Val with Num {
    override def echo {
      println("Number: " + name)
    }
  }
  val ONE = StatusVal(1, "One")
  val TWO = StatusVal(2, "Two")
  val THREE = StatusVal(2, "Three")
}

Status.values foreach (s => s.asInstanceOf[Num].echo)
```

Comment: Type casts are the dead of strongly typed programming language.

Comment: Unfortunately, you need to use them sometimes, like it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried implicit conversions? Remember to keep the scope tight:

```
// I have deliberated stolen @cyrillk example :). 
// Just add this line to the body os Status (Enumeration Object)
implicit def valueToNum(v: Value): Num = v.asInstanceOf[Num]
```

`Value` will be implicit cast to `Num`, so:

```
Status.values foreach (s => s.echo) // works!
```

[Working Example](http://ideone.com/m8lljb)

---

Chek out a [Better example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6546480/664577) by [Sean Ross](https://stackoverflow.com/users/824653/sean-ross).

Comment: Good catch. It makes use of Enumeration even better.

Comment: The answer is the same.  I am a big enemy of casts :)

Comment: If you think so, go ahead and cook your own implementation (I would personally take  the cast over reinventing the wheel). Rules are made to be broken.